# Android Webview: xhr-polling keeps page 'loading'

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, socket.io, android-webview, long-polling

I have a WebView running a page containing a socket.io client that connects to a remote node.js server. The problem is that because websockets are not supported in the Android webview (they are in the Android Chrome browser), it falls back to xhr-polling.

I have an `onProgressChanged` listener for the `WebChromeClient`, but the xhr-polling keeps the page continuously loading. When I log the progress, it reaches ~90-95% and gets no further. This means that I cannot dismiss any loading indicators or perform any other actions that require the page to be fully loaded.

Is there anyway I can make Android think that the `xhr-polling` is not part of the page loading? Or is there a workaround? I haven't tested it with `jsonp-polling` yet. I would prefer a solution to this issue, rather than a hack/workaround, but ultimately I just want my app to work.

*P.S, I am aware of native libraries for socket.io and WebSockets on android. However, this all needs to be done in a WebView.*

Thanks

Comment: Did you reach any conclusion since then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!

On the socket.io-client apparently there's a special defer if it's XHR + webkit browser in here:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/0.9/lib/util.js#L203

As you can see, 100ms it's not enough for a mobile phone, I had to change it for at least 500ms! I think the authors didn't remember this use case! Patch the socket.io-client with this and profit :)

Answer (score 0):

Until I can discover a better solution, I am using a workaround. I noticed that every time, the progress will reach at least 90%. So, instead of waiting for 100%, I wait for 90%. Even at 90%, I can see that pretty much all of my page has loaded, there are no visual changes made to the page after 90%.

Comment: How's that for a workaround? If the page isn't fully loaded, it will always show the Spinning wheel or the loading bar.. Did you get any success on debugging this problem?

Comment: Not found any other alternatives so far no. It won't always show the spinning wheel or loading bar because I hide and cancel them once the progress hits 90. The page is still technically loading still, but it's only the socket stuff, nothing that actually affects the page.

Like I said, its far from from ideal, but it works.

Comment: This is happening to me but with the native android browser, so I can't hide and cancel. Sometimes it fully loads, sometimes it sticks on the 90% just like you. Funny that I can't find too much info regarding this issue, you where the only person that stated exactly what it's happening.

Comment: Yeah it's weird. Glad to know I'm not alone with this problem though. Maybe the latest version of node will help it. I think the new version of socket.io being released soon as well.